# window.location.hash = " "; prevent scrolling to the top?

Tags: javascript, fragment-identifier

in my website i set the url adress using

```
window.location.hash = 'project_name';
```

but if i want to clean the adress url from any hashes (when i close a project) and i set

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

it happens the page scrolls up to the top page

there is any way to clean up the url without any side effect?

thanks

Comment: You could assign a non–existing anchor, but that's not really "cleaning" the URL up :D

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's the `onhashchange` event, but it cannot be cancelled reliably across browsers to prevent scrolling.  The best solution is to record the scroll position before changing the hash location and reset it afterwards.  For example, the following code will catch a click on any link ― that doesn't stop propagation ― with a href value of `#` and prevent the page from scrolling vertically:

```
document.onclick = function (evt) {
    var tgt = (evt && evt.target) || event.srcElement,
        scr = document.body.scrollTop;

    if (tgt.tagName == "A" && tgt.href.slice(-1) == "#") {
        window.location.href = "#";
        document.body.scrollTop = scr;           
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you're changing the hash through script, you can use the following code:

```
var scr = document.body.scrollTop;
window.location.href = '#';
document.body.scrollTop = scr;
```

Either of those methods can be adjusted to avoid scrolling individual elements or scrolling the page horizontally. Note that you *can* [remove the entire hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5298684/94197) (including the `#`) without causing navigation or scrolling in modern browsers by calling the `pushState` or `replaceState` functions.

Comment: You can also temporarily create another element with that `id` at the `scrollTop`.

Comment: fyi,it is not working in Firefox and only most of the time in Chrome. It gets in the ohhashchange function but the browser still scrolls (tried preventing default too).

Comment: @JCarter: you're right, I've removed that part.  The other part of my answer is probably the best solution, I've improved on it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document/14690177#14690177), solved my issue.

Comment: in 2019 this technique appears not to work in Chrome

Comment: `history.pushState(null, null, "#")` ended up being the modern solution, however keep in mind this will not trigger hashchange event

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem and came here for an answer. Just found out there is a very easy way:

```
window.location.hash = ' ';
```

Basically you are setting it to '# ', since the space doesn't exist, it doesn't move. When you revisit the page, it also doesn't treat it any differently than just #

Comment: This should be the accepted question, in my opinion

Answer (score 8):

First off, thanks for your solutions - @Andy-E and @JustMaier.

However, I had a problem getting it to work based on Andy E's second code block in Firefox and JustMaier's code in chrome.

So I did a mash up of those two code blocks and it works just as intended on both browsers

```
var scr = document.body.scrollTop;

window.location.hash = ' ';

document.body.scrollTop = scr;
```

My two cents, taking nothing away from the real JS ninjas, mentioned above. : )

Answer (score 2):

document.body.scrollTop [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js#answer-28633515), also latest Chrome versions seem to be unstable here. The following should work:

```
  var topPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  window.location.href = '#';
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = topPos;
```