# jQuery Tabs Selected Tab Prevent Jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs, an click on a tab it add hash to the url

```
jQuery( "#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
        }
    });
```

problem is when i click on a tab it opens but it scroll and jump to top of the page

Normal tabs[image]

When i click on tab [image]

Anyone know how to fix this issue

Comment: Why you adding # in url... ? if add then it will jump to top anyhow

Comment: The whole problem have nothing to do with JQuery UI Tabs at all. You are manually putting # and updating location hash which jumps to top of page. Look at this question to prevent that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715073/window-location-hash-prevent-scrolling-to-the-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `history.pushState()`. Check [History Api docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
jQuery( "#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        history.pushState(null, null, '#' + ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked fine but when i refresh the page hash tag seems removing, is there have a way to keep hash tag