# How to redirect to the current tab after clicking save on the current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have implemented `nav-tabs` in my project using bootstrap.When we enter the application,Home tab is active.When i make changes in the other tabs and press save button,the page is going to the Home tab.

I want the tab on which i've made changes to be active.

The below is similar code i've used in my project.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
         <div class="container">
        <div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#search">Search</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <h1>Hospital Data Solutions</h1>
        <p>Financial Analysis Database</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="about">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <p>Cost Reports and Financial Analysis Nationwide Database</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="subscribe">
        <h1>Annual Subscription</h1>
        <p>Purchase an annual subscription to access all cost reports.</p>
    <h2>Individual Cost Reports</h2>
    <p>Purchase individual cost reports directly from us in .pdf, .xs, .csv formats.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="search">
        <h1>Search our database</h1>
        <p>Search content goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="logout">
        <h1>logout</h1>
        <p>Logout fx goes here.</p>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/nh6ma48r/11/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808205/keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add the selected tab hash to the url.
Here's an example with JQuery :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
     var hash = $(this).attr('href');
     location.hash = hash;
});
```

Next, you need to show the tab linked to the hash added to the url when you load the page :

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var $nav = $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]');
    hash && $nav.trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems, basically what you need to do, is to add the class `active` to the `<li>` tag, when entering the page, and removing it from other `<li>` elements.

```
<li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#about" aria-expanded="false">
        About
    </a>
</li>
```

You could achieve that with `jQuery`. Just set the appropriate class during page initialization. With `jQuery` you will also have to bind the appropriate events to the elements, as Martin Lezer explains in his answer:

The question is, how to you remember the state of the application between refreshs. Here are some possibilities:

1. Cookies: Set a cookie with the status, each time you click on a tab
2. Local storage or session storage of the browser. Same principle as 1
3. Location-Hash: see answer of Martin Lezer here.
4. URL-Parameters: You could use those to remember the app-state, but I would recommend against it, because usually you do not want to have this kind of information in the URL.

1 and 2 are persistent, that means, you can come back tomorrow and the application can init with the same state

3 and 4 are not persistent, you need to pass that information each time you enter the application (which is fine, during a session)

Hope that helps.