# Bootstrap-Wizard how to overwrite a default active tab (first tab) to previous active tab after saving or submitting data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using  [Bootstrap-Wizard](https://github.com/gilluminate/Bootstrap-Wizard) with 6 tabs and each tab has to save form data button, after saving data in one tab the page is getting reloaded so that first tab becoming active tab by default but I want to make that tab active  in which I saved the data.

i.e: I am saving data in 5th tab after saving data in 5th tab only 5th tab should become active not the first tab.

when we save the data in one tab page is reloading, so index value becoming 0 after the page reload so when i click next button the second tab becoming active (index value 1), its not actually going to the next tab to the active tab.

for better understanding i'm adding similar questions below please go through this,

**stack overflow question**

1, [keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808205/keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload)
2, How do I keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload?
3, Bootstrap 3: Keep selected tab on page refresh

**Bootstrap-Wizard:**
github.com/gilluminate/Bootstrap-Wizard

**[Page Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1twF.jpg)**

Comment: Create a demo if possible in `jsfiddle`

Comment: sorry could not create:( ,  for your better understanding i'm adding more similar questions below please go through this,  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808205/keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
else{ $('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); }
});
```