# How to remember the active li item after refresh

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap as web UI. When I click one li item, it redirects to a new webpage and the active item will be the first item again, how can I sovle this problem?

```
    <ul id="profileTabs" class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">My Match</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: by adding class appropriate active class on redirected page.

Comment: By using persistent storage as localStorage/cookie or sending params to requested page

Comment: [DOM Storage guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Comment: we need code, can't fix something we can't see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use **localstorage** or **cookies** to manage that.

```
$(function() { 
  //for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab' instead of 'shown' in the next line
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    //save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(e.target).attr('id'));
  });

  //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
  var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
  if (lastTab) {
      $('#'+lastTab).tab('show');
  }
});
```

Code Courtesy [How do I keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload/10524697#10524697)

In above code tabs are used but try replacing with `li's` you expect

Comment: Thanks, what's the meaning of 'a[data-toggle="tab"]' ?

Comment: I update my code, please help me! I'm new to boostrap and jquery.

Comment: Just checked, when copy/paste other people answer, you should quote it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524697/1414562 ...

Comment: This works when the page do need to refresh, but when I need to refresh the page, it just active the first item, my code is updated in my question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This could be achieved with just css. You need to apply classes to the html tags on the pages and individual classes to each li item.

e.g. **HTML** (for the profile page)

```
<html class="profilePage" >
...
    <ul id="profileTabs" class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="profileMenuItem"><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="aboutMenuItem"><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="matchMenuItem"><a href="http://localhost/ojr/user/edit/Charles0429" data-toggle="list">My Match</a></li>
    </ul>
...
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.profilePage .profileMenuItem,
.aboutPage .aboutMenuItem,
.matchPage .matchMenuItem {
    /*active styles here*/
}
```

**N.b.**
`<html class="profilePage" >` would change depending on which page you are on

E.g.
For the My Match page

```
<html class="matchPage" >
```

For the About Me page

```
<html class="aboutPage" >
```

Comment: Once a time, there is an only one active item. When I click one Item, it redirects to one page(may be not the current one), So how could CSS achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand you fully. But the technique I have provided can achieve your goal as far as I understand it. Essentially - applying styles to specific elements depending on what page you are on.