# Does Zend Flashdata exist?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-4, zend-framework2

In Laravel, CodeIgniter etc we do have the function to set some data in the Session for 1 request.

Does something like this exist for Zend? Should one even want to use this or is this considered a bad example?

Of course I know about the flashMessenger, but this is only intended for messages as the name says already. I googled about it alot, but cannot seem to find anything related to this topic.

So, to be clear, I want to know the following:

- Is it a bad example or habit to use the session for data that is just used one request?
- Does Zend Framework 2 include something like a (Laravel example) Session::flashdata($key, $value) ?

Comment: I've not used Laravel, however searching the term `flashdata` it sound just like the `FlashMessenger` plugin in ZF2. So are you looking to just add additional data to the session (such as an `array`, rather than a message string)?

Comment: Yes. Im looking to post an array with additional data to the next request (par example;  which jQuery tab should be openend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store any data within a session in ZF2 you can (or rather should) use an instance of  [`Zend\Session\Container`](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.session.container.html).

Each 'container' accepts a 'namespace' parameter that allows you to maintain session information independently between containers.

For instance the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger` that you have mentioned internally uses a session container with a specific namespace, `FlashMessenger`.

You can create and add any data to a session container (Check out the [`Session Storage`](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.session.storage.html) for more info, the default is `Zend\Session\Storage\ArrayStorage`)

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

$container = new Container('my_custom_namespace');
$container->foo = array('bar');
$container->hello = 'test';
```

**Edit (Tabs)**

The issue you will have with tabs is when you click on a new tab you will not be sending a new HTTP request (unless you use AJAX). Therefore you will need to either store the current tab in local storage or a cookie from *javascript*.

You can also pass the current tab via GET or POST parameters. I personally append to the HTML anchor `#` between requests (rather than storing it within sessions).

A basic example might be

```
// Append the currently selected tab in the anchor
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'ul.nav-tabs > li > a', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
});
// check if there is already a value and display that tab
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

So any URL with a anchor will show the matching tab. If you are posting from a form you can add it to the action attribute.

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="/the/form/target#tab-3">
```

Comment: Great answer, but, it only answers my second question. How are the thought of using the session for data-exchange? It's is possible to do it with the url (eg. url/tab1/) but I prefer clean url's without mentioning the tab I'm on. Thats where I thought of the session.

Comment: Sessions are fine, although I don't think that I would be doing so server side (as you would need a new request), if you just want to remember the current tab. Perhaps you could should consider [a javascript soultion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload)?

Comment: Its a post and then a redirect if form has success. I want to return to the tab where the initial form was editted. The tabs are jQuery already.

Comment: @Chilion I've updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: great. It was more like an example, none the less, usefull! I indeed also use Ajax, so I'm sending a request. Thanks for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

See the [namespace expiration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html) section of the Zend Session "Advanced Usage" documentation. You can use a call to `Zend_Session_Namespace::setExpirationHops(1)` to emulate the 'flash' methods in Laravel.

---

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't realise that it had been removed in ZF2. Apparently, it [does exist in ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Session.Container.html#setExpirationHops), but they have moved it to the new container system, which seems to have replaced the old namespace system.

Comment: This is for ZF1, the question specifically requests ZF2.

Comment: Im aware of this function indeed in ZF1, Im looking for ZF2 as Alex and my beginpost already stated. None the less, thanks for the efford

Comment: Yes, you're both quite right - sorry! Have updated my answer.