# How do I keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload? With typescript?

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I want to How do I keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload? with the help of type script.How can i do this.My issue is same as :-

[1]: [How do I keep the current tab active with twitter bootstrap after a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload) but i want to do this typescript.How can i?

Comment: You just need to convert answer from that question; from JavaScript to TypeScript.

Comment: but i don't know how to convert it and i am also a new in  a typescript .

Comment: Sorry but I am not in the mood to convert it for you. Wait for someone to do it for you or try to learn and figure it out yourself.

Comment: can u give any working fiddle or plunker example for this?

Comment: TypeScript is the same a Javascript, but with type annotations.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to do this typescript.How can i

Lucky for you TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/javascript/recap.html

[image]

So the code sample from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524697/390330 works **just fine**

```
// for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab', for bootstrap 2 use 'shown' in the next line
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
});

// go to the latest tab, if it exists:
var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
    $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

NOTE: I didn't use the wrapping function as I hope you are using modules. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html