# Highlight or Bold particular Navbar item which has multiple links.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to CSS and J Query. Here i want to highlight Nav bar item which has multiple links under the page. Each links leads to a new page.

The problem is nav bar active class is just disappearing when i click another link which leads to different page, loosing its active state. How to maintain the active state of nabvar item even if i navigate to any other page.

header1.php contains navbar and i am including it using **include("header1.php")** in required files where i have multipe links.

**header1.php**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="adminhome.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span</a>
</div><div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li class="<?php active('totalapplications.php');?>" id='a1'><a  href="totalapplications.php">Applications</a></li>
<li class="<?php active('block.php');?>" id='b2' ><a  href="block.php">Block</a></li>
   <li class="<?php active('roomallotment.php');?>" id='r3'><a  href="roomallotment.php">Allotment</a></li>
    <li class="<?php active('deallotsingle.php');?>" id='d4'><a  href="deallotsingle.php">De-allotment</a></li>

    <li class="<?php active('viewblocks.php');?>" id='v5'><a  href="viewblocks.php">Hostel Details</a></li>
    <li class="<?php active('student_details_master.php');?>" id='s6'><a  href="student_details_master.php">Student Database</a></li>
    <li class="<?php active('searchallotment1.php');?>" id='s7'><a  href="searchallotment1.php">Search</a></li>
```

**sample.php**

```
<?php
      include("databaseconnection.php");
      include("header1.php");?>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <a href="student_details.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick="boldButton1(1)">Fresh Applications</button></a></div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <a href="renewalstudent_details.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn block">Renewal Applications</button></a></div>
```

header1.php is included in sample.php which has multiple page links. How i can maintain the nav item active state even after navigating to another page by those links.

Please check below links for images.
Thank You.

[!Image which show navbar item active.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCXfQ.png)

[!This image shows the page is navigated to some other page and navbar item lost its active state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpYOx.png)

Comment: Use $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]. Like **if($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]==student_details.php){echo 'class="active"'}**

Comment: This might be the answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523433/how-do-i-keep-the-current-tab-active-with-twitter-bootstrap-after-a-page-reload