# which library is overriding the $?

Tags: jquery, django, requirejs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use jquery/bootstrap/ and requirejs

Loading js files works perfectly and I checked that bootstrap sets $.fn.tab = someFunction;

but then, inside requirejs's callback function, calling $(foo).tab('show') results in an error saying that tab is not available for the object.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tab'`

Everything loads fine, I confirmed they do by printing a log.
But I guess $ is redefined or something.
Where should I start to look?
`grep '$\s*='` ?

my code is rather long and I posted under a different question: [jquery, bootstrap 3.0, and requirejs. can't use bootstrap's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561755/jquery-bootstrap-3-0-and-requirejs-cant-use-bootstraps-functions)

I'm using django if that makes any difference

Comment: Is it really `$(foo)`? Because usually it would be more like `$('#foo')`. Note that the argument is a string. Also, the error message suggests that the 'tab' widget has not been loaded correctly, rather than `$` being overwritten.

Comment: yes, well ok it's more like $('#foo'). I know the code works, because It worked before I tried using requrejs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that bootstrap hasn't finished loading at the time you try to use it.  Try changing your bootstrap shim in the requirejs config to this:

```
shim: {
  "bootstrap": {
    deps: ["jquery"],
    exports: "$.fn.tab"
  }
}
```

RequireJS will wait to execute any code depending on bootstrap until $.fn.tab is set.

Comment: I checked (by logging) the $.fn.tab is assigned before the code which uses $.fn.tab..

Comment: Try logging $.fn.jquery (once outside of the requirejs scope, and again where you're having the issue) to make sure it's the version you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. U should use jquery no conflict function to avoid other library that use the same $ symbol.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
     // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Now with many framework use $ such as prototypejs i think it is a good convention to follow. 
Reference :

- http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/