# Twitter Bootstrap - losing fade class between page tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've enjoyed reading the solution for inter-page navigation and activating the bootstrap tab anchors here: 
[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload)

However, the fade class that is present and allows for fade effects when switching between tabs seems to get wiped out when navigating to a specific tab from another page.

For example, on page1.html, I see the tab fade effect when clicking between #mytab1 and #mytab2.

However, when starting on page2.html and clicking on a link "page1.html#mytab1" - I'm taken to the 1st tab on my page1.html, but when navigating between tab 1 and 2, the fade effect isn't there.

So, how do I make sure the fade effect stays around when navigating from another page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the tab you navigate to (from external site) contains the classes "fade" and "in".

For instance on page load

```
if(!$('.tab-pane.active').hasClass('fade')){
     $('.tab-pane.active').addClass('fade');
}
if(!$('.tab-pane.active').hasClass('in'){
     $('.tab-pane.active').addClass('in');
}
```