# How load to show a Bootstrap Tab on page load without flickering the first tab first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a navbar that looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#personal" data-toggle="tab">Personal Info</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#con-sib" data-toggle="tab">Contacts/Siblings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#state-fed" data-toggle="tab">State/Federal</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#eth" data-toggle="tab">Ethnicity</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#placement" data-toggle="tab">Placement</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#medical" data-toggle="tab">Medical</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#sch-release" data-toggle="tab">School Release</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have some javascript code that sets the correct active tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash) {
        var selectedTab = $('.nav li a[href="' + hash + '"]');
        selectedTab.trigger('click', true);
        }
    });
```

The above code works well (ignore the second parameter to `.trigger()` -- it's used elsewhere in my application), but with one caveat. When the page loads, the first tab is loaded and then correct tab is quickly displayed after that.

How can I prevent the first tab from getting displayed before the correct tab is displayed?

Comment: Maybe just remove the active class from the html?

Comment: I ended up going with a solution like this.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hide the class `active` which is the first tab on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.active').hide();
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash) {
        var selectedTab = $('.nav li a[href="' + hash + '"]');
        selectedTab.trigger('click', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or even better not put the active class there in the first place. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether OP can modify his HTML or not, but that is also an option :)

Comment: Just used this without the active hide, didn't this used to work before without the hack?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than waiting for `ready()` to fire, try putting your code into an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/13019) and placing it right before the closing `</body>` tag (and *after* the jQuery and Bootstrap `<script>` elements it depends upon).

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function(){
        // your code here
    })();
    </script>
</body>
```

This way it'll fire as soon as the document has finished parsing.