# Any way to get BootStrap tabs to be activated via the URL?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using BootStrap's Tabs ( http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs ). Is there a way to get it so that when you got to example.com/#8 it brings you to the tab marked 8?

Current code:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="MyTabs">
  <li><a href="#8" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#7" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#6" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
...
</div>
```

I don't normally use JS because I have not learned it yet but any help would be awesome!

Comment: @DavidMulder Sorry if it was a duplicate, I didn't have time to look up others similar (yes I did for a few minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

From: [The Same Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload) but I would suggest attempting your own research in the future. An example search I would use to find an answer would be something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=bootstrap%20open%20tab%20from%20link&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: OMG! Thanks SO MUCH! While that google search would of worked, i found this worked better thanks.