# bootstrap open tab from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Javascript / jQuery newbie here. This question has been asked numerous times before but I am not able to implement any of the solutions and make them work on my single-page website. My code below. So far, I have tried variations of the following (without success):

- [Linking to specific twitter bootstrap tabs from URL on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374630/linking-to-specific-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-from-url-on-same-page)
- [Jump to specific tab from another tab with Bootstrap's nav-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360112/jump-to-specific-tab-from-another-tab-with-bootstraps-nav-tabs)
- [Any way to get BootStrap tabs to be activated via the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092756/any-way-to-get-bootstrap-tabs-to-be-activated-via-the-url)
- [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)
- [show tab with external link with onclick in bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428779/show-tab-with-external-link-with-onclick-in-bootstrap-3)
- [how to link twitter bootstrap tabs from hyper link on otherpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582688/how-to-link-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-from-hyper-link-on-otherpages)
- [Bootstrap linking to a tab with an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625211/bootstrap-linking-to-a-tab-with-an-url)
- [Externally Linking to a Tab, Tab not changing, Bootstrap 3.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867556/externally-linking-to-a-tab-tab-not-changing-bootstrap-3-3-5)
- [Go to Specific Tab on different Page link click and toggle active class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990508/go-to-specific-tab-on-different-page-link-click-and-toggle-active-class)

Below is the closest I have got to a solution. What am I missing?

```js
$(document).load(function() {
  $('#section-A a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="section-A">

  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>Some text here ...
      <a href="#tab-1">Tab 1 hyperlink text</a> blablabla
      <a href="#tab-2">Tab 2 hyperlink text</a> and blabla
      <a href="#tab-3">Tab 3 hyperlink text</a> and blabla
      <a href="#tab-4">Tab 4 hyperlink text</a> and bla.
    </p>
  </blockquote>

</section>


<div id="section-B">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4 title</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">Tab 1 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">Tab 2 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">Tab 3 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane">Tab 4 Lorem ipsum …</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Could you explain more?

Comment: Thanks a lot @SaidbakR, this worked. I have a quick follow-up question: How can the jQuery code be modified so that the active state of the <li> element also changes? In other words, what would be the best way to toggle the <li> active class? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not able to understand what do you need exactly?! The `li` active class is already toggled, i.e the blue background is appeared on click its tab and it disappeared on click over another tab!

Comment: ... I should have deactivated my content and script blockers before posting the question – sorry about the confusion, and many thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$(document).ready()` instead of `load`. Checkout [this demo](http://jsbin.com/dobiloreya/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 7):

Replace `$(document).load` to `$(document).ready`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#section-A a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="section-A">

  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>Some text here ...
      <a href="#tab-1">Tab 1 hyperlink text</a> blablabla
      <a href="#tab-2">Tab 2 hyperlink text</a> and blabla
      <a href="#tab-3">Tab 3 hyperlink text</a> and blabla
      <a href="#tab-4">Tab 4 hyperlink text</a> and bla.
    </p>
  </blockquote>

</section>


<div id="section-B">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3 title</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4 title</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">Tab 1 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">Tab 2 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">Tab 3 Lorem ipsum …</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane">Tab 4 Lorem ipsum …</div>
  </div>

</div>
```