# Loading a link directly into an active twitter bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I make a link to go from Page A to Page B.

Page B has a tab (Twitter Bootstrap) with two panes.

How can I load Page B from Page A AND specify which pane to load?

Comment: `<a href="B.htm#ID_OF_THE_TAB_PANE">LINK</a>`

Comment: When I load the page, I load it with an active tab. This works when I click the link to the active tab but it does not work on the other tab.

Comment: There are several good options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload

Comment: @jme11 I tried those... I am having the same issue that I mentioned in my comment above. I have one of my tabs active

<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
...
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
...
</div>

Link to b.html#tab1 works. Link to b.html#tab2 does not work.