# Loading a specific bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a tab system in my view folder and i need to load a specific tab when the page loads.

I know this exact question has been asked here [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload)

but everything i've tried hasn't worked. Ultamitly i want to load a tab depending on what link is pressed but right now i am just trying to load a specific tab off the start.

in my view file I have

```
<head>
    <script>


    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
    })

    $('#myTab a[href="#email-skills"]').tab('show');        
    </script>
</head>
```

and my tab system looks like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style = "margin-top: 10px" id="myTab">
                <li class = ""><a href="#basic-computer-skills" data-toggle="tab">Basic Computer Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#advanced-computer-skills" data-toggle="tab">Advanced Computer Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#multi-media-skills" data-toggle="tab">Multi-Media Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#word-processing-skills" data-toggle="tab">Word Processing Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#spreadsheet-skills" data-toggle="tab">Spreadsheet Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#presentation-skills" data-toggle="tab">Presentation Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#email-skills" data-toggle="tab">Email Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#internet-skills" data-toggle="tab">Internet/Network Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#social-media-skills" data-toggle="tab">Social Media Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#online-skills" data-toggle="tab">Online Collaboration</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know there are lots of posts on how to do this and bootstrap has their own javascript on their site but nothing has worked. Does anyone know what i could be doing wrong?
Also, my tabs work when i click on them so i don't think its a syntax error. Just all my attempts to make it load a specific tab has failed. I know about class = "active" but that doesn't help me for my end goal.

I am also using the gems

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
$(function () {

       $('ul.nav a.classtobeloaded').tab('show')


 })
```