# Bootsrap Twitter tabs - go a specific tab when the page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am developing an web app. In some of the web pages I am using Twitter Bootstrap pane tabs. below is my code.

I am trying to go to a specific tab when the page reloads. 
For example: when I am in the www.mywebsite.com/c.html the first active tab is 'bc' when I go to 'cc' and refresh the page it goes back to 'bc'. I want it to stay in 'cc'. I need to be able to do something like this www.mywebsite.com/c.html#cc But this does not work.

I looked at [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink) but could not find an answer that fits my code. I tried changing the class names still no luck.

```
<div class="wp">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#bc" data-toggle="tab">bc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cc" data-toggle="tab">cc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lc" data-toggle="tab">lc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pc" data-toggle="tab">pc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sc" data-toggle="tab">sc</a></li>                                        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content tab-content-inverse">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="bc">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cc">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="lc">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pc">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="sc">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the anchor part of the URL by using [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) in your JavaScript/jQuery.

Then, append it into the following JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('.nav li a[href="#lc"]').click();
```

You'll simply insert the value you pull using location.hash after the href= portion, which will then be clicked.

Change the value in the following Bootply example and run it to see how it works.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/J9vLhrLG0a)**

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for responding to me though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some code in JavaScript that will run when the page loads and check the # part of the url (`window.location.hash`). Take a look at the bootstrap website for how to toggle a certain tab: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Unless the asker specified they were using Twitter Bootstrap 2.x.x, I wouldn't link them to what's essentially outdated documentation....

Comment: @MattD Oh snap, I was in a rush and didn't realise I was looking at an old URL. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited with an up to date URL.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I changed the class names to tabs and the event to click event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {               
            var hash = document.location.hash;
            var prefix = "tab_";
            if (hash) {
                $('.tabs a[href=' + hash.replace(prefix, "") + ']').tab('show');
            }
            $('.tabs a').on('click', function (e) {                    
                window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
            });
     });
```