# How to organize single page app navigation with JQuery and ColdFusion 2016?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, coldfusion, single-page-application, jquery-templates

I have started my new single page application. So far I was able to create login/authentication process and build the templates for the Home.cfm page. While looking around the web I see that JQuery can provide navigation template for single page app. My current code is old fashion and here is what I have. So in root folder I have `index.html` and here is content of that page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=Login.cfm" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

You can see the `url` in meta tag redirects to Login.cfm. First thing I would like for my website to show only web site name instead of what I have now:

```
https://example.com/Login.cfm
```

After user entered Username and Password in Login.cfm I will process authentication with Auth.cfc where I check user credentials. If they successfully pass that step I lead them to `Home.cfm`. This page is main page of my SPA. Then my url looks like this:

```
https://example.com/Home.cfm
```

In `Home.cfm` I have code that is organize and loaded in different `.html` files. Code does work and I have decent performance but I would like to use JQuery navigation template method something like MVC. I would prefer to use my current technology stak JQuery, Bootstrap 3, HTML5, CSS and ColdFusion 2016. I looked over few examples but still did not understand how to reorganize my application. I use `IIS` web server on my site. Here is example of my `Home.cfm` page:

```css
#main-container {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.tab-box {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  ;
}

ul.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
ul.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
ul.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SPA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> <b>Welcome to My Application!</b></p>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="main-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="active"><a href="/tab1-page" data-container="tab1-container">Tab 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/tab2-page" data-container="tab2-container">Tab 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/tab3-page" data-container="tab3-container">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" role="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="confirmation" data-popout="true" role="button" id="log_out">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="tab1-container">
      <cfinclude template="Includes/Tab1.html">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2-container">
      <cfinclude template="Includes/Tab2.html">
    </div>
    <div id="tab3-container">
      <cfinclude template="Includes/Tab3.html">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" src="JS/Tab1.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="JS/Tab2.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="JS/Tab3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I use JQuery to navigate user to different template once they click on the menu. Basically this will show/hide the elements on the screen. If anyone can provide some good tutorial or example on how this can be organize please let me know.

Comment: Couple of things. You are not exactly using just jQuery. Bootstrap is in the mix. Even though the question is broad, I would add AJAXing the tabs into the mix. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679749/go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink-where-tab-is-loaded-by-ajax. Last but not least, you are about 50% the way there to a full JS solution. Angular, React, and VueJS can cover the front end. And ColdFusion can serve up the data on the backend.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I already have logic that triggers ajax call based on the tab focus. I'm little confused what do you mean by `you are about 50% the way to a full JS solution`? So you are recommending  one of the JS frameworks Angular/React/VueJS?

Comment: Yes, you leave CF to provide the data API that powers a solely Javascript based front end user interface. No server-side HTML generation. Take a look at this to build the skeleton UI, no jQuery needed. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Yes, that is my recommendation.