# Open an active tab from external link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

im working on a project with bootstrap 3. 
I want to link from the "home" page to a specific open tab. 
i read and test so many opportunities but nothing worked.

My latest here:

```js
$activetabbuehne = (params.activeTab is null or params.activeTab == 'tab_a') ? 'class="active"' : '';
$activetabhoehe = (params.activeTab == 'tab_b') ? 'class="active"' : '';
$activetabaudio = (params.activeTab == 'tab_c') ? 'class="active"' : '';
$activetabstudio = (params.activeTab == 'tab_d') ? 'class="active"' : '';
$activetabsonder = (params.activeTab == 'tab_e') ? 'class="active"' : '';
$activetabinstall = (params.activeTab == 'tab_f') ? 'class="active"' : '';
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  <li $activetabbuehne><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">BÜHNENBAU<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li $activetabhoehe><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">HÖHENARBEITEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 26px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li $activetabaudio><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">AUDIO-, VIDEO-, LICHTTECHNIK<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li $activetabstudio><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">STUDIO<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li $activetabsonder><a href="#tab_e" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">SONDERLÖSUNGEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li $activetabinstall><a href="#tab_f" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">INSTALLATIONEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the Link i use for the tests on the dev.page:

https://amphire.de/dev/leistungen/?activeTab=tab_a

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you mixing languages? It looks like you are trying to print a JS string in HTML just by placing it in the tag. Unless you are using some framework that process the code, that won't work

Comment: Thx, i used the following answer to build it in my own. I found the solution very interesting if it worked :)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441158

Comment: That solution is in pseudo-code. You need to adapt it to JS and to your particular case (still it won't work as it will only highlight the link but not show the content)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I´ll try an other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible JavaScript solution for what you want to do would be to trigger the click event on the link specified by the parameter. It would work like this:

- Read the parameter from the URL (you can use this [solution by Haim Evgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979997/3695983))
- After the links have been displayed on the page, trigger the click for the corresponding link.

This would be a sample code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  <li><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">BÜHNENBAU<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">HÖHENARBEITEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 26px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">AUDIO-, VIDEO-, LICHTTECHNIK<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">STUDIO<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_e" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">SONDERLÖSUNGEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_f" data-toggle="pill" style="font-weight:500;">INSTALLATIONEN<span style="font-weight:500; float:right;font-weight: 700;float: right;font-size: 23px;color: #db001b;">+</span></a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

// function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/979997/3695983
function gup( name, url ) {
  if (!url) url = location.href
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

// get the value of the activeTab parameter
var targetTab = gup("activeTab", window.location.href);

// trigger the click so that tab activates and shows content
$("a[href='#" + targetTab + "']").click();

</script>
```