# How can I Implement Javascript to open a specific tab with SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

So I'm working on a project where I'm building a website and I have many pages that include tabs from Bootstrap that use jQuery to work. They work really well and I love them but on my homepage I want to be able to link icons to specific tabs. Once clicked they should move the browser to that page and that tab should open instead of the default active tab. I've found numerous examples of javascript on how this would work but I don't know how I can get the JS to work on my SharePoint site.

```js
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)

The above code is from that answered question and I'm wondering if someone can show me how to use this on my SharePoint pages.

Comment: Have you tried to add the ID of tab as anchor on the link?
Like this: http://yourlink/yourpage#idTab

Comment: Yes, I figured it out I'll post an answer.

Comment: Fine, just don't forget to vote as usefull comment.

Comment: I'm so new that I don't even know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've worked on this a ridiculous amount of time for the problem I was actually having. I used the above code along with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery with CDN links in the page. That was correct. I also used the right notation for the url which is www.examplehere.com/blahblah#tab_tab1. The problem I was having was that I loaded this script at the top of the page, prior to the HTML 5 actually loading and making the tabs contained in the body on the SharePoint site. This meant that it went through the code to switch the open tab to the one dictated by the url but the code didn't have anything to change the tabs to since the tabs didn't exist.

So if you want this to work in SharePoint 2013. Save the above code as a .js file, link to it via a Content Editor Web Part, use the urls with the #tab_tab1 syntax as above, and please do yourself a favor and put the Web Part at the bottom of the page unlike I did.