# How To Activate Bootstrap Tab via URL

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">Content inside tab A</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">Content inside tab B</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C">Content inside tab C</div>
</div>
```

Tab A is the default tab in most situations. But I want to visit tab B after this page loaded  in certain conditions. Can I just visit the page via different URL  with something like HTML anchor?

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: Have you tried looking into the documentation? I believe Bootstrap's JavaScript library comes with a feature that takes care of this. Check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)