# Turbolinks and Bootstrap Tab activation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I am basically facing the same problem as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink), under the additional context of Rails' Turbolinks.

I am using this piece of code

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    /* Show tab from anchor */
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

    /* Update URL anchor after selecting tab */
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
        var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop();
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
        $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
    });
```

Which does work for manual page reload (F5) and for cache restore, but not after reloading the page from a Turbolinks click*.

**When clicking a turbolinks link, if there is some cache of the page, then that cache is first restored and the good tab is shown, but then thre is still a request to the server to get the last contents, and once that request arrives and is parsed, the tab "switches back" to the original one*

My bootstrap code looks like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#student" role="tab"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#mentor" role="tab"><%= </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#company" role="tab"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <br />
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="student" role="tabpanel">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mentor" role="tabpanel">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="company" role="tabpanel">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 5 comes with Turbolinks 5. The solution was just to change the name of the event listener

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
```