# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab with Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried to apply the method found on this post : [specific tab hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)

But i don't understand why it doesn't work for me. I'm sure it's a little mistake but i'm not an expert in javascript.

If you could give me some help : 
here is [my page](http://chine-exclusive.com/item.php?id=1) but if i try to access directly on my "devis" tab with [this link](http://chine-exclusive.com/item.php?id=1#devis) it doesn't work.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Show your relevant code and we can help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

***Your external link:***

```
<a href="#Devis" data-toggle="tab">Devis From Outside</a>
```

***And JS*** *(to extract tab hash from page URL and update tabs view)*:

```
<script>
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = this.href.split('#');
        $('.nav a').filter('a[href="#'+target[1]+'"]').tab('show');
    })
</script>
```

See [**JsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/gy0k69w1/), *I hope it works for you, Thanks !*