# Open and scroll to tab from url hash (JS/Jquery/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a comment system with one deep nesting. I'm using bootstraps javascript file, but only the collapse and animate css styling. So I don't use `nav-tab` and such

A button exists on all comments that have a reply. The number `1` refers to the ID of the parent (replies of comment with the id of 1).

`<a class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#replies_1">X replies</a>`

Then I have a div, that is the container for all children of the parent comment

`<div class="collapse" id="replies_1">`

When I click on the anchor, as you would guess, this div gets appended the class `in` and transitions nicely to open and show the comments children.

I have tried one thing that worked, except for the scrolling part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash != "") {
        $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
    }
});
```

This opens up the correct tab, which is great. However, since the tab has the class `collapse` which has the css rule `display:none;` and adds the inline rule `display: none;`

Now, my script doesn't manage to scroll to the correct location, because the collapsed element has those rules.

Though, I don't really need to scroll to the replies, but the parent.

**So what I really need is to scroll to another anchor id that has the same suffix ID, but a different prefix, but still open the replies tab as I do with the code above**

Since the children are inside a tab with an id of `replies_{id}`, I could scroll to the parent which is a `ul` item with the id of `comment_{id}`

The `ul` looks like this: `<ul class="comment__item" id="comment_{id}">`

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7862233/215552?

Comment: Do you have a link to a working example?

Comment: Can you please share your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash != "") {
        var end_id = window.location.hash.split('__')[1];
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("[id$='__"+ end_id +"'").offset().top},"slow");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, If I understood your question correctly.
Actually you can get the hashtag from that url and find the id from your hash `#replies__{id}` then collect that `{id}` from it and prefix the required text of another id `#comment__{id}` so you are ready to perform the same.

for example

//consider this event after hash is collected

```
hashValue = "replies__1232" //assuming the default value 
oldId = hashValue.split("__")[1] // collect id

//now append id to required prefix
$("#comment__" + oldId).click(function(){
   //required stuff here   
}) ;
```