# Activate an external tab using Href from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

i want to activate a tab using an href, the tab is on another page. how can i do it, this is my code :

First html page:

```
<html>
<body>

 <a href="Mytransfers.aspx#__tab_Main_ctl00_TabCodntainer1_TabPanel4"  data-toggle="TabPanel4"><u><b>how to transfer funds ?</b></u></a>


</body>
</html>`
```

Second Html page that i want to activate it tab:

```
 <html>
   <body>
  <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel4" ID="TabPanel4">
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                   Bon à savoir
                   </HeaderTemplate>
 </body>
 </html>`
```

Comment: This does not sound very legit...

Comment: can i navigate to another page and point to a tab using a property in the href link ?

Comment: Yes you can ... check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9393768/2887133 could be usefull

Comment: Create a  css property and this class  dynamically .

Comment: can someone take the time to show me an example using my links?

Comment: @DaniP the example didn't worked !

Comment: with this code it points into the tab but doesn't activate it !