# Reload a specific tab after call ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like reloading my page after a call Ajax. It works with location.reload() but i'm redirect to the first tab. How can i just reload my tab ?

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="tab" data-target="#profile">
    <h3 class="tab-title active" data-target="#profile">Mes informations</h3>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-target="#prayers">
    <h3 class="tab-title" data-target="#prayers">Mes prières</h3>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-target="#pains" id="tab-pains">
   <% if (@notification && @notification.count > 0) %>
     <h3 class="tab-title" data-target="#pains">Mes demandes <span id="tab-notification">(<%= @notification.count %>)</span></h3>
   <% else %>
     <h3 class="tab-title" data-target="#pains">Mes demandes </h3>
   <% end %>
 </a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".user-show-delete").on("click", function(e){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var pain_id = $(this).data("id-pain");
  console.log(id)
  console.log(pain_id)
  var current_index = $("#tabs").tabs("option","active");
  swal ({
    title: 'Effacer',
    text: 'Voulez-vous supprimer cette prière ?',
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#B56969',
    cancelButtonColor: '#B4D8C0',
    confirmButtonText: 'Oui',
    cancelButtonText: 'Non'
  }).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: '/pains/' + pain_id + '/prayers/' + id,
      success: location.reload(),
    });
  });
 });
});
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [open specific tab on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink).

In short, you should add the hash of the tab to the URL. Then when the page loads you open the correct tab using JavaScript.