# Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on different page in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, tabs

I use bootstrap to create the static site.
In my home page i have a link to redirect to specific tab of another page.
I use this script code, it works perfect in bootstrap static html page.
Code in JS

```
    $(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Code in Html

```
<a href="tyres.html#menu7">
```

It will redirect page to tyre.htmil tab menu7, work perfect.

Once I move the html to themes of wordpress, this function does not work properly in php. it only redirect to the page, not on specific tab anymore.

Code i tried in php of home page of wordpress

```
<a href="tyres#menu7">
```

and

```
 <a href="tyres.php#menu7">
```

Do i need to replace Permalink name to ID? or what is right format i need to use in php? or if there is anything i need to change of my JS code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the wordpress site_url(); function in the anchor tag like this to redirect and open the tab on destination page

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/your-page#tab-hash">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it shows "Object not found!", any idea? this is only part make crazy to finalize my website, otherwise i have to change the design...

Comment: I think it is something wrong of the script code to work with php or wordpress url, could you help me to check please

Comment: thanks again, but it is only going to the page, but not go correct tab.

Comment: You have to setup some JavaScript like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/7862233/3709903

Comment: Thanks, there was classes of html code in tab caused problem, i recode that part, it works fine now!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead

```
<a href="/tyres/#menu7" data-toggle="tab">
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not open link anymore.