# How to redirect in Symfony 5 to specific tab data target

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, bootstrap-4, routes

User is on the 3rd tab and clicks on a DELETE button. I would like to redirect user to the same 3rd tab on the page.

```
**Template:**

<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-target="#cars" data-toggle="tab" >Cars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab" >Messages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-target="#extras" data-toggle="tab" >Extras</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cars" class="tab-pane active">
      SOME TAB 1 CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="messages" class="tab-pane fade">
      SOME TAB 2 CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="extras" class="tab-pane fade">
      SOME TAB 3 CONTENT
    </div>
</div>


**Controller:**

   /**
     * @Route("/extra/{id}", name="extra_delete", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function extraDelete(Request $request, Extra $extra): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$extra->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($extra);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('car_index');**
    }
```

**I ve already tried this:
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('car_index').'#extras');
but doesnt work.

Thank you

Comment: hi peter, this is not related to symfony or php at all, of course this is about bootstrap and as it is one of bootstraps js-components (tabs) u will have to include a little script, already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)

Comment: thank you @john Smith for the correct hint. The linked topic pushed to the correct direction. For the exact solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the solution was indeed Javascript.

1. In the controller I put a parameterized URL:

   ```
    return $this->redirectToRoute('car_index', ['param' => 'extrakTab']);
   ```
2. In the template I run this script:

   ```
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const parameter = urlParams.get('param')
    if(parameter !== null){
        let elements = [];
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-pane');
        toggleClass();
        function toggleClass(){
            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].classList.remove('active');
                elements[i].classList.add('fade');
                }
            }
        var element = document.getElementById(parameter);
        element.click();
        }
   ```