# Twitter Bootstrap 5 Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How could you link to bootstrap 5 tabs directly as with previous bootstrap methods according to?:

[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink)

I've tried the following approach:

```
var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, ""); // ^ means starting, meaning only match the first hash
if (hash) {
  var someTabTriggerEl = document.querySelector("#" + hash + "");
  var tab = new bootstrap.Tab(someTabTriggerEl);

  tab.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the tab trigger is from a `<ul>` list, and the query string hash is the target in the `href`, then the Bootstrap 5 method for showing a tab when the page loads would be:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#someTarget">Some Target</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const trigger = document.querySelector(`ul.nav a[href="${window.location.hash}"]`)
  const tab = new bootstrap.Tab(trigger)
  tab.show()
})
```

The above does not check for invalid query string hash names or valid dom elements; add as-needed.

Comment: Works nicely after the typos are fixed.

`addEventListner` and `boostrap`

Comment: @JustOneMoreQuestion - good catch; updated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently solved this with:

```
var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
if (hash) {
  var triggerEl = document.querySelector("#" + hash + "-tab");
  triggerEl.click();
}
```