# Going to Anchor Text inside a Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, anchor

I'm trying to create a URL link that opens a particular page at a particular element (a form).

But the element is inside a bootstrap tab on that page.

To get the correct tab to open I've followed this javascript [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Go to Specific Tab on Page Reload or Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862233/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-reload-or-hyperlink#comment57946728_9393768)

As I now have a # hashtag for the tab in the URL I can't seem to find how to add second hashtag or element reference.

Any thoughts on how I can open the page to the form inside the second tab?

My tabs:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <ul class=" nav-tabs nav">
         <li id="tab-1" class="active nav-tab nil-tick ">
             <a href="#stays" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">List<span class="pronoun"> a</span> Stay </a>
         </li>
         <li id="tab-2" class="nil-tick">
             <a href="#experiences" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">List<span class="pronoun"> an</span> Experience </a>
         </li>
         <li id="tab-3" class="nil-tick">
             <a href="#other" style="color:unset" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Other </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

And the section I wish to link to

```
<form class="subscribe_form" method="POST" style="background:white" id="experience-application-form" autocomplete="off">
```

And the javascript

```
  // Javascript to enable link to tab
  var hash = document.location.hash;

  var prefix = "tab-";
  if (hash) {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash.replace(prefix, "") + '"]').tab('show');
  }

  // Change hash for page-reload
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `tab('show')` on the anchor (`a`) element. Here are two event listeners, on for the page load and one in the case the hash changes at a later point (when the user clicks a tab or the user write another hash in the address bar).

I cleaned up the HTML a bit. I couldn't figure out if you structured it in the right way, so I grabbed an example from [Navs and tabs · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#tabs).

```js
// when the page loads, test if hash exists and
// show that tab
$(document).ready(function() {
  let hash = document.location.hash;
  if(hash){
    $(`a[href="${e.target.location.hash}"]`).tab('show');
  }
});

// when the hash changes, test if hash exists and
// show that tab
window.addEventListener('hashchange', e => {
  let hash = e.target.location.hash;
  if(hash){
    $(`a[href="${e.target.location.hash}"]`).tab('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#stays">List<span class="pronoun"> a</span> Stay</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#experiences">List<span class="pronoun"> an</span> Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#other">Other</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for those changes.

We're not there yet though - only the bookmark on the default tab works.  The bookmark in other tabs is not opening their respective tabs, nor navigating to the tagged elements.

Am not sure if its related to the css file or not.  I haven't been able to use the suggested bootstrap v5.3.2 css file as it clashes with our site css.  We are still using boostrap v3.4.1 css.