# Prevent page scroll when hash is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hashtag

The following code is causing the page to scroll down to the bottom of the page.  How do I prevent the page from scrolling in this situation?

```
// If note is clicked, then append id as hashtag at end of url
$("span.note").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Use a different `id`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document

Comment: Thanks.  This link provided the insight I needed.  What I needed to do was prepend some text to the hash value and then take that text off later when I used the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally  you could try to add: `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

To disable scroll without removing hash in window.location

You can **temporarily** **remove id of your node** before changing **location.hash**
Then you set **id** again on node

```
// Prevent default on anchor link click
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeHashWithoutScrolling($(this).attr('href'));
});

// Prevent instant scroll of browser
function changeHashWithoutScrolling(hash){
    if($(hash).length > 0){
        var $el = $(hash);
        var elId = $el.attr('id');
        $el.removeAttr('id');

        window.location.hash = hash;

        $el.attr('id', elId);
    }
}
```