# Prevent go to anchor link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, preventdefault

This is my jQuery code, when it reads the window.location.hash it adds a CSS class to an element and it is shown. But I cannot do to prevent going to that anchor. I tried preventDefault() but it seems to not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cotizar(n){
  gotoSlide(n);
  $('#cotizadores > div').removeClass();
  $('#cotizadores > div').eq(n).addClass("cotizador_activo");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.location.hash != ''){ 
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    index = $(".tab-content > div ").children("#boton_"+hash).index();
    cotizar(index);
    clearInterval(slideival);
}

$(".slides > div > a").on('click',function(event){
  window.location.hash = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  index = $(this).parent().index();
  cotizar(index);
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});


});
</script>
```

[This is my site url](http://www.tusseguros.com.ar/sitio), try clicking 'ABRIR COTIZADOR' in any of the slides.

Thanks!

Comment: Try put `cotizar` function inside document ready

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update window.location.hash without jumping the document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara), this is the best answer I found:

```
el= $('#anchor_element');    
id= el.attr("id");    
el.removeAttr('id');
window.location.hash =id;
el.attr('id',id);
```

This option prevent flickering. Credits to [Tobias Buschor](https://twitter.com/tobiasbu), seen in [Lea Verou Blog's comments](http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/)