# Smooth scroll to data-href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a lot of smooth scroll scripts on stack, and I have adopt them a lot in the past. As I do not want to use `<a href="#">` links, I am using `<buttons data-href="">`. This is my current code:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.smooth').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'data-href');
        $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
                window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    alert('smoothness');
});
```

And the necessary html part:

```
<button id="downarrow" data-href="#features" class="smooth">
  <span>scroll down</span>
</button>
```

This works great, as seen right here: <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/43cun8qk/)</kbd>

I do not know why, but it does not work in my live site with the same code. You can check its build here: <kbd>[**FULL DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/43cun8qk/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document. Check if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a CSS issue with this line :

I removed "overflow" property of this :

```
article#wrapper{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

[You can see it in your fiddle right here](https://jsfiddle.net/43cun8qk/6/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. As the `header {position: fixed}` is not a bug, I suggest you remove this from your answer. Removing `overflow: auto` from my `#wrapper` is the only necessary thing to do! :) thanks for your help!

Comment: You're right about "header {position: fixed}" line. 
Glad to help you ! :)